# Prometheus & grafana: wrong total in legend

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a metric with amount of tasks picked from queue. I use this query for prometheus in graphana:

```
sum by (namespace) (increase(dbqueue_picked_tasks_total{service="$service", namespace="$environment"}[1m]))
```

For choosen time there was only 1 task picked from queue. But on graph I see 3 points with values 1.2 and in legend I see total 3.6. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to change the focus of the mouse from the query text field in grafana to another place just to update the chart. Your query seems correct. Is it the case that you select to show the `total` or `max` field on grafana legend?

Comment: @Felipe Yes, I've marked checkbox to show total in legend in grafana interface

Comment: interesting. could you please try to reduce or increase the `[1m]` at the end of your query? I think it is related to that

Comment: Yes, if I reduce, I see less points and less total

Comment: But it seems strage for me

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is necessary to change the focus of the mouse from the query text field in Grafana to another place just to update the chart.

In your case, the `Total` legend option from Grafana is summing up the points based on the time frame `[1m]` of the Prometheus query. Use the `Current` legend option on Grafana to see the last value. Or use the `Max` option to see the unique maximum value from the whole timeseries.

[image]

Comment: "Current" is zero now - how could it help?
If I can change time frame to 30s, I see only one not null value - 1.5 (while I expect 1) and I see Total 1.5. It's better but I don't get how to you Prometeus to get the expected results.

Comment: maybe what you are looking for is the `Max` option? The `Total` will sum up all the values that you see on the chart. The `Current` is the last value on the timeseries.

Comment: yes, I want to sum up to get total amount of tasks which was picked from queue for period and compare it for example with amount of tasks successfully processed. but it doesn't match with amount of records in logs.